# Deploying a SpringBoot into another server in a docker through Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm new to CI/CD process.

We have a model deploying a spring boot application through jenkins in docker in a same machine.

We was searching in internet how to deploy an application to another server, the only key which we have got is through SSH agent. I hope SSH is only for communicating.

Can we have a complete example how to deploy into another server and what are the other preventive measure to be taken into account.

Kindly guide us

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Jenkins pipeline you need to define a stage for publishing the docker image and in your infrastructure you need a repository that stores your artifacts and docker images.

[image]

[image]

Repositories I know are `Nexus` or `JFrog Artifactory`.

So your server1, at the end of the pipeline, will upload the stable docker image to Nexus.

To execute the docker images in another server (not using an orchestrator) you may use Ansible.

On the net you can find a lot of sources, for example: https://www.codementor.io/mamytianarakotomalala/how-to-deploy-docker-container-with-ansible-on-debian-8-mavm48kw0